# Using If Else statement in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT IF(book_id=2, 'NTR', if(book_id=5,'CBC', if(book_id=1,'CBC','Repair')) AS   
'STATUS',
COUNT(IF(book_id=2, 'NTR', if(book_id=5,'CBC', if(book_id=1,'CBC','Repair'))) AS 
Total
FROM book_entry AS b
WHERE last_updated=(SELECT last_updated FROM book_entry WHERE book_code=b.book_code ORDER  
BY last_updated DESC) AND (SELECT description FROM book_categori AS c, book_item AS i  
WHERE c.id=i.id AND i_item_code=b.item_code) = "NOVEL" 
GROUP BY IF(book_id=2, 'NTR', if(book_id=5,'CBC', if(book_id=1,'CBC','Repair')))
```

From this query, I got this result:

```
STATUS      BIL
---------------
CBC         70
Repair      58
```

It is not like the reuslt I want. What I want is like this:

```
STATUS      BIL
---------------
CBC         70
Repair      58
NTR         0
```

Can anyone teach me what I need to change in my query to get that result?

Comment: Something in the `where` clause is filtering out the row that you want.  You don't provide enough information to determine which clause is doing it.  Please provide sample data.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not really understand what are your saying. I'm new in this. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: `WHERE ...` = problem, which is why u get wrong result. Also does NTR exist on your table or when its 0 its not registered on the table?

Comment: There are no ID for NTR in table(book_entry). That is why I want it view as NTR=0 in the result. What I suppose to change? I really don't know what changes I need to do. Do I need to change from IF..statement to other type of statement to get the result that I want?